Is a hyperplane defined by $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} = 0$ a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
I'm trying to understand the concept of hyperplanes and their relationship to subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Here's my understanding:

A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a flat, $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace that passes through the origin.
The equation $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} = 0$ defines a subspace that is the set of all vectors $\vec{x}$ orthogonal to the normal vector $\vec{w}$.
This subspace is the hyperplane through the origin because every vector $\vec{x}$ in this subspace satisfies the condition of being orthogonal to $\vec{w}$, meaning $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} = 0$.
When $b = 0$ in the general equation $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} = b$, the hyperplane passes through the origin and is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, consisting of all vectors orthogonal to $\vec{w}$.

so tldr -- the hyperplane is defined by the set of all $\vec{x}$ which satisfies $\vec{w}\cdot \vec{x} = 0$ in any arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^n$ space.
So, my question is: Is this understanding correct? Does the equation $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x} = 0$ indeed define a hyperplane that is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Thanks for any clarification!

It is a mixture of correct and incorrect. Any linear algebra textbook will clear your misconceptions.

You can prove these on your own. Show that elements of the hyperplane are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. You'll need to use that $w_1 \cdot x=0$ and $w_2 \cdot x=0$ to show that $(w_1+w_2)\cdot x = 0$ and $\lambda w_1 \cdot x =0$.

Any hyperplane which passes through the origin is indeed a subspace of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's also perfectly fine to think of any given hyperplanes as being defined as the set of all vertices that are orthogonal to a given nonzero vector $\vec{w}$ (can you think of why we need this non-zero requirement?), since the space that you obtain is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. In other words, you can't get "knocked off" the hyperplane by adding together scaled copies of vectors from the hyperplane.
Another way to think about it is as follows: you can pick a basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vec{w} \in \beta$. The set of all vertices orthogonal to $\vec{w}$ is precisely the vector space generated by $\beta \; \setminus \; \{\vec{w}\}$, since all basis vectors have to be linearly independent. This space will have a dimension that is one less than the original dimension was, since we removed precisely one basis vector.

Yep Thanks. I know well "any hyperplane which passes through the origin is indeed a subspace of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$" -- i guess this was more directed to, is the hypeplane defined by the set of all $\vec{x}$ which satisfies $\vec{w}\vec{x} = 0$?
other:

I'd say we need the non-zero requirement so $\vec{w}$ isn't simply a point at the origin. otherwise orthogonality / nullspace would be trivial (being the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ space


@vxnuaj yes, that is correct. Some texts even define a hyperplane precisely in this way (see for example https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/The_Calculus_of_Functions_of_Several_Variables_(Sloughter)/01%3A_Geometry_of_R/1.04%3A_Lines_Planes_and_Hyperplanes) -- here the point $p$ is always equal to zero, to ensure that the plane passes through the origin.
